# How to find missing dates in monthly data series?

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I am working with monthly widget inventory with occasional missing months of data. I would like to do a 'gaps and islands' type analysis but I can't get the implementation to work properly (see sqlfiddle). I am trying to create new columns specifically listing the gap and island start and stop dates:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a212a/2

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the below.[SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3fee06/28)

```
  WITH StartingPoints AS
     (SELECT ID, OCCURRANCE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id, OCCURRANCE) AS rn
        FROM dates_test A
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM dates_test B
               WHERE B.ID = A.ID
                 AND EXTRACT(month FROM B.OCCURRANCE) =
                     EXTRACT(month FROM A.OCCURRANCE) - 1
                 and EXTRACT(year FROM B.OCCURRANCE) =
                     EXTRACT(year FROM A.OCCURRANCE))),
    EndingPoints AS
     (SELECT ID, OCCURRANCE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id, OCCURRANCE) AS rn
        FROM dates_test A
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM dates_test B
               WHERE B.ID = A.ID
                 AND EXTRACT(month FROM B.OCCURRANCE) =
                     EXTRACT(month FROM A.OCCURRANCE) + 1
                 and EXTRACT(year FROM B.OCCURRANCE) =
                     EXTRACT(year FROM A.OCCURRANCE)))
    SELECT S.ID,
           EXTRACT(month FROM S.OCCURRANCE) AS start_range,
           EXTRACT(month FROM E.OCCURRANCE) AS end_range
      FROM StartingPoints S
      JOIN EndingPoints E
        ON E.ID = S.ID
       AND E.rn = S.rn;
```

you can find the  start_gap and end gap below

```
                        WITH StartingPoints AS
     (SELECT ID, OCCURRANCE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id, OCCURRANCE) AS rn
        FROM dates_test A
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM dates_test B
               WHERE B.ID = A.ID
                 AND EXTRACT(month FROM B.OCCURRANCE) =
                     EXTRACT(month FROM A.OCCURRANCE) - 1
                 and EXTRACT(year FROM B.OCCURRANCE) =
                     EXTRACT(year FROM A.OCCURRANCE))),
    EndingPoints AS
     (SELECT ID, OCCURRANCE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id, OCCURRANCE) AS rn
        FROM dates_test A
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM dates_test B
               WHERE B.ID = A.ID
                 AND EXTRACT(month FROM B.OCCURRANCE) =
                     EXTRACT(month FROM A.OCCURRANCE) + 1
                 and EXTRACT(year FROM B.OCCURRANCE) =
                     EXTRACT(year FROM A.OCCURRANCE))),
    MissingPoints AS
     (SELECT S.ID,
             EXTRACT(month FROM S.OCCURRANCE) AS start_range,
             EXTRACT(month FROM E.OCCURRANCE) AS end_range,
             EXTRACT(YEAR FROM E.OCCURRANCE) YEAR_of_OCCR
        FROM StartingPoints S
        JOIN EndingPoints E
          ON E.ID = S.ID
         AND E.rn = S.rn),
    i1 as
     (select level num from dual connect by level <= 12),
    ms11 as
     (select ID,
             start_range,
             end_range,
             lead(start_range, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY id, year_of_occr, start_range, end_range) as am_i_ms,
             lead(year_of_occr, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY id, year_of_occr) as miss_year,
             year_of_occr
        from MissingPoints),
    miss_month1 as
     (select id,
             start_range,
             end_range,
             DECODE(end_range + num, 13, 0, 14, 0, end_range + num) missing_month,
             year_of_occr
        from ms11, i1
       where ((end_range + num < am_i_ms or sTART_Range = end_range) and
             end_range + num <= 14) or (year_of_occr<> miss_year and am_i_ms >=0 and  am_i_ms <=12 and end_range + num <= 14)
       order by year_of_occr, missing_month),
    miss_month as
     (select *
        from miss_month1 A
       where not exists
       (select 1
                from miss_month1 B
               where A.ID = B.ID
                 AND (A.missing_month = B.start_range AND
                     A.missing_month = B.end_range)
                 and A.year_of_occr = B.year_of_occr)
         and decode(end_range, 12, -1, end_range) < missing_month),
    StartingmisPoints AS
     (SELECT A.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id, year_of_occr, end_range, missing_month) AS rn
        FROM miss_month A
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM miss_month B
               WHERE B.ID = A.ID
                 and b.start_range = a.start_range
                 and b.end_range = a.end_range
                 AND B.missing_month = A.missing_month - 1
                 and b.year_of_occr = a.year_of_occr)),
    EndingmisPoints AS
     (SELECT A.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id, year_of_occr, end_range, missing_month) AS rn
        FROM miss_month A
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM miss_month B
               WHERE B.ID = A.ID
                 AND B.missing_month = A.missing_month + 1
                 and b.start_range = a.start_range
                 and b.end_range = a.end_range
                 and b.year_of_occr = a.year_of_occr))
    SELECT distinct  S.ID,
           S.start_range,
           S.end_range,
           S.missing_month start_gap_range,
           E.missing_month end_gap_range,
           E.year_of_occr
      FROM StartingmisPoints S
      JOIN EndingmisPoints E
        ON E.ID = S.ID
       AND E.rn = S.rn
```

Comment: This is getting very close to what I am looking for. Ideally it would show the date field where the island/gap begin and ends (e.g. creating 4 new columns: island start/stop, gap start/stop)

Answer (score 0):

With some modifications, I have converted your query to -

```
WITH StartingPoints AS
(
    SELECT ID, OCCURRANCE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OCCURRANCE) AS rn
    FROM dates_test A
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM dates_test B
        WHERE B.ID = A.ID AND EXTRACT(month FROM B.OCCURRANCE) = EXTRACT(month FROM A.OCCURRANCE) - 1)
),
EndingPoints AS
(
    SELECT ID, OCCURRANCE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OCCURRANCE) AS rn
    FROM dates_test A
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM dates_test B
        WHERE B.ID = A.ID AND EXTRACT(month FROM B.OCCURRANCE) = EXTRACT(month FROM A.OCCURRANCE) - 1)
)
SELECT S.ID, EXTRACT(month FROM S.OCCURRANCE) AS start_range, EXTRACT(month FROM E.OCCURRANCE) AS end_range
FROM StartingPoints S
JOIN EndingPoints E ON E.ID = S.ID AND E.rn = S.rn;
```

From you fiddle it seems, You are using Oracle and Oracle doesn't support table aliases with "AS" keyword. If this is not your expected result, Please share your expected result also.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4e0cbb455ee72f6d0e4071132084a074).

Comment: I am very sorry, the oracle flag was an error. Thank you for attempting to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LEAD` analytic function to find the gaps:

```sql
SELECT id,
       ADD_MONTHS( date_from, 1 ) AS missing_from,
       date_to - INTERVAL '1' SECOND AS missing_to
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         TRUNC( occurrance, 'MM' ) AS date_from,
         LEAD( TRUNC( occurrance, 'MM' ) )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY TRUNC( occurrance, 'MM' ) )
           AS date_to
  FROM   dates_test
)
WHERE  ADD_MONTHS( date_from, 1 ) < date_to
ORDER BY id, date_from;
```

So for your test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dates_test ( id, value, occurrance ) As
-- march and september and october are missing for both IDs-
SELECT 1, 10, DATE '2014-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 10, DATE '2014-02-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 10, DATE '2014-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 10, DATE '2014-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 10, DATE '2014-06-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 10, DATE '2014-07-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 10, DATE '2014-08-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 10, DATE '2014-11-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 10, DATE '2014-12-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 10, DATE '2015-01-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 10, DATE '2014-01-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 10, DATE '2014-02-03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 10, DATE '2014-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 10, DATE '2014-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 10, DATE '2014-06-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 10, DATE '2014-07-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 10, DATE '2014-08-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 10, DATE '2014-11-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 10, DATE '2014-12-07' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 10, DATE '2015-01-07' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> ID | MISSING_FROM        | MISSING_TO         
> -: | :------------------ | :------------------
>  1 | 2014-03-01 00:00:00 | 2014-03-31 23:59:59
>  1 | 2014-09-01 00:00:00 | 2014-10-31 23:59:59
>  2 | 2014-03-01 00:00:00 | 2014-03-31 23:59:59
>  2 | 2014-09-01 00:00:00 | 2014-10-31 23:59:59
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=25ff203a8a15c7af3bce52fa39116a06)*